# Linq Read XML with <br> tag

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a xml file, structure is like following:

```
<template><body>public DiffSectionType Type<template:br/>{<template:br/><template:tab/>get<template:br/><template:tab/>{<template:br/><template:tab/><template:tab/>return _Type;<template:br/><template:tab/>}<template:br/>}</body></template>
```

I would like to be more readable, like:

```
public DiffSectionType Type
{
   get
   {
      return _Type;
   }
}

<template:br/> => new line
<template:tab/> => tab
```

I can read body string, but not able to put it in correct format,
I have tried

```
var document = XDocument.Load("template.xml");
var body = from element in document.Elements("template").Elements("body")
               select element;
foreach(var v in body)
{
  Console.WriteLine(v.Value);
}
```

Comment: Can you use `<![CDATA[]]>`? But even so, I would not use lines to parse a xml. The purpose of XML is to define the structure using elements, not lines.

Comment: This is html not xml.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex to solve this so something like this:

```
        string str = @"<template><body>public DiffSectionType Type<template:br/>{<template:br/><template:tab/>get<template:br/><template:tab/>{<template:br/><template:tab/><template:tab/>return _Type;<template:br/><template:tab/>}<template:br/>}</body></template>";
        str = Regex.Replace(str, "<template:br\x2F>", Environment.NewLine);
        str = Regex.Replace(str, "<template:tab\x2F>", "\t");
        str = Regex.Replace(str, "(<\x2Ftemplate>)|(<template>)", "");
        str = Regex.Replace(str, "(<\x2Fbody>)|(<body>)", "");
```